# Is it possible to write a program that will fool a device into thinking my laptop is a compatible USB stick?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, device-driver

I have a Roland TD-11 electronic drumset and there are a select few USB sticks that the drumset's sound module supports.  Attempting to load/save files from the module results in the message "USB memory not connected here" if you don't have a supported USB stick plugged in.

Rather than buying a supported USB stick, can I just write a program that will allow me to transfer data to/from this console?

I've looked into libusb but I'm not sure how to identify whether or not I can write and read data from the sound module.

Answer (score 0):

Buying a supported USB drive will almost certainly be cheaper and easier.  If you wanted to make something yourself, there are a variety of microcontroller development boards available that can be used as programmable USB device.  Here is just [one example](https://www.pololu.com/product/3109).  You would have to pay some money for the microcontroller board and then spend a lot of time learning how USB works and learning about embedded development.